# Jhipster doesn't run latest generator (3.2.0) in existing app

Tags: jhipster, yo

I have an existing jhipster app that I am trying to keep up to date with the generator.  I successfully updated the app to 3.1.0 generated code and would now like to update to 3.2.0.  I have installed the 3.2.0 generator and can create a new app with that version (generator shows version 3.2.0 when I run "yo jhipster").  However when I run "yo jhipster" in the root of my existing app, I the generator reports that it is using jhipster 3.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, please read comments in this pull request https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/3562

Try deleting `node_modules` folder of your project before running `yo jhipster`

Comment: Deleted node_modules, regenerated and updated the 100+ diffs to upgrade to 3.2.  Worked like a champ.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an issue (I also have that problem all the time and hate it) or a feature (it's working as expected, so you can have one JHipster version per project)... Anyway the solution is indeed to delete `node_modules`